# Php error log not working correctly

Tags: php, apache, error-log

i have error in my page but it is not logs in to the log file
i have set

> display_errors:Off
>   display_startup_errors:Off
>   error_log:error_log
>   log_errors:On

i have restarted apache after configuration
but it is not working

just checked the apache file /etc/httpd/logs/error_log file
it contain the error but why the error_log does not creating in the folder in which error occurs

Comment: can you identify the errors that appears ?

Comment: yes i made mistake my self to test that but it doesn't logged  is also try to put error  using this function but this too not worked error_log('An error');

Comment: Well, what does the http servers configuration say about which error log file is used?

Comment: where i have to look for that

Comment: did you set path for error_log?

Comment: i used this ini_get('error_log'); it gave output 'error_log'

Comment: So "not working" means that the error log is created in the Apache log folder rather current working directory? Do you want to scatter error logs all around your site?

Comment: yes i want in current working directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this in your php file

```
ini_set("log_errors", 1);
ini_set("error_log",$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/logs/php-error.log");
```

Give write permission to the folder logs and its file, then check the file in logs folder.

```
error_log:error_log
```

`error_log` not has correct path, set a correct path like below

```
log_errors = On
error_log =  "C:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log"
```

Comment: give all permission to the folder `logs` and its files and try again

Comment: friend this worked is set 777 permission on folder logs and file php-error.log  but i have to include this two line every time i write any new file please why this is to be done and what permission will be safe to give

Comment: you can write these lines in separate file and include this in all files like a db connection file and keep the log in separate folder and give permission to this. I don't think it will be harmful.

Comment: do you have any idea why the correct php.ini settings are not working and we have to set seprately

Comment: log_errors = On
error_log =  "D:\xampp\php\logs\php_error_log"
use this in php.ini it will work

Answer (score 0):

You said:

> just checked the apache file /etc/httpd/logs/error_log file it contain the error ...

which means:

- loggine php errors works
- all errors are written to /etc/httpd/logs/error_log

You also said:

> ... but why the error_log does not creating in the folder in which error occurs

Your php.ini directove **error_log** specifies where your want your error log to be. Now it is default. Specify different log file location and you'll have it in different place. There is no why - it lands where it is said to be.